# Android Printing

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, pdf, printing

We have two smartphones and two tablets (variously LG, Asus, Samsung, all Android KitKat) and an HP wireless printer (3059a).

Using HP's ePrint app we can print from all devices but it's not straightforward; most of the prints we make are of emails and webpages, meaning we have to save as PDF and then print, and even then we have to laboriously specify paper size (A4) and a few other things, and to remember to delete the PDF afterwards. I have also checked out Google's CloudPrint but that's not much better.

Is there any way to set up printing for one (or just a few) touch operation?

Comment: Can you provide individual steps for how you are printing. I have a Galaxy S3 and a Galaxy Tab 4. Using the HP connection works perfectly and simply.

Comment: I shall provide details as @paulmz requested, but I'm off on holiday so it won't be until October.